# When did this post go CW?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, community-wiki, revisions-list

Looking at the revision history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2823571/revisions) it isn't apparent that the question is CW. It was not initially created as CW so when did it get converted to it? Did 4 edits trip the Auto-CW rule? (3 by Author, 1 by other user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question gets 30 answers it automatically becomes CW.

See the [FAQ for Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for more info about them than you can shake a waffle at.